# How to Fill SQL query's parameters automatically?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a query like below:

```
select ct.ID,
           ct.B_CODE,
           ct.G_F_ID,
           ct.T_CD,
           ct.STATUS,
           ct.E,
           ? as TYPE_CODE
    from ln.CUSTOMER ct
    where 1 = 1
      AND B_CODE = ?
      AND G_F_ID = ?
      AND INSERT_DATE > ?
      AND INSERT_DATE < ?
      AND STATUS in (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

and value of its parameters are given in an array separated by comma like this:

```
[50, 1001, 1734508, 2019-01-13, 2019-01-13, 10, 20, 30, 40]
```

For testing this query all the time I have to put array parameters one by one sequentially in their corresponding place in query instead of ? characters. Final query will be like this:

```
 select ct.ID,
      ct.B_CODE,
      ct.G_F_ID,
      ct.T_CD,
      ct.STATUS,
      ct.E,
      50 as TYPE_CODE
    from ln.CUSTOMER ct
    where 1 = 1
    AND B_CODE = 1001
    AND G_F_ID = 1734508
    AND INSERT_DATE > 2019-01-13
    AND INSERT_DATE < 2019-01-13
    AND STATUS in (10, 20, 30, 40);
```

Sometimes this array is too long (100 items in it) and it is bothersome and doing it without tool is error prone too. Is there any tool or plugin in `Intellij IDEA` to overcome this issue? Or I have to write a plugin by my own?

Answer (score 1):

Use [User parameters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html) to substitute them with actual values at the moment of execution:

[image]